# Quicktime recording: help, I did 1/2 of an interview with my headphones on, interviewee can barely be heard :(

Tags: audio, headphones, quicktime

I did a horrible newbie mistake. 
Recorded about half of a really cool interview with my headphones on, without realising it. I can hear my voice, coffee shop noise, and very very light sounds from the interviewee. Is there a way I could clean the noise to only get the interviewee? So sad.

Comment: I’ve used Adobe Audition (which has tools designed to isolate dialog, reduce noise, etc). Or google “adobe audition alternatives” or “audio editing tools” or what have you, and you’ll see alternatives. Or if a video interview, many video editing packages have built in audio tools, too. Bottom line, there tons of tools that can help, but they can be expensive and complicated, and they will help, but not likely solve the problem entirely. And pulling the voice from the background is going to be hard enough, but trying to separate it from your voice is a big ask…

Comment: FWIW, I would encourage you to avoid the tendency to over-process it. It's better to use a light touch and simply apologize for the audio quality to your audience in the intro in the final production. IMHO, a little noise is less distracting that over-processed audio. When folks first discover these tools, they tend to “crank it to 11” and it can end up being more distracting than a little background noise would be. So, sure, reduce noise a bit, match loudness LUFS, etc., but do not over process it…

Comment: BTW, I think it’s safe to say that anyone who has done any audio work (especially true for those of us who have had to wear multiple hats at a shoot/recording) has likely done this at least once. I certainly have. Unless you have a dedicated audio engineer on site, monitoring the levels, this is extremely easy to do. It’s a tough lesson to learn. I feel for you.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

Assuming the levels were set for your own voice, in close proximity to your mouth, that would make the other voice 1 or 2 meters away & also likely speaking to the back of the mic, which would usually be in its rejection zone. That is going to be impossibly low to successfully recover with any clarity.

The best you could hope for would be to edit out each time the other person speaks to a separate audio track; boost the volume, then see if you can manage to de-noise it... that's the fun part.
Decent de-noiser plugins start at expensive & go up to *really, really* expensive.
Even so, they cannot work miracles.

Izotope RX is about the best there is.
They do a 'home' bundle for a mere $129- [RX Elements](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/repair-and-edit/rx/rx-elements.html)
the ['RX Standard'](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/repair-and-edit/rx/rx-standard.html) package for an eye-watering $399
or the full-blown ['RX Advanced'](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/repair-and-edit/rx/rx-advanced.html) package for a "please sit down first & take a deep breath" $1199

<sup>No affiliation, merely a satisfied user</sup>